# YouTube Data API - concurrentViewers throwing an error

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get the concurrent viewers from a live video, but I keep keep getting an error whenever I am trying to store the value in a variable.

[image: Error in this picture]

Code snippet is below.  The error is on the line `var videoConcureentViewrs...`

```js
var part = 'snippet,statistics';
var params = {'id': videoID};

var response = YouTube.Videos.list(part, params);
var video = response.items[0];
var videoViewCount = video.statistics.viewCount;
var videoConcurrentViewrs = video.liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may then take the [tour].

Comment: Please obey to SO guidelines: do not post images containing source code or error messages. Do post these as plain ([formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) text.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: @Tanaike, yes it helped out.  The missing 'liveStreamingDetails' was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In this case, please include `liveStreamingDetails` in the value of part.
- And, at `YouTube.Videos.list`, `part` of argument can be given as an array.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var part = ['snippet', 'statistics', 'liveStreamingDetails'];  // Modified
var params = {'id': videoID};

var response = YouTube.Videos.list(part, params);
var video = response.items[0];
var videoViewCount = video.statistics.viewCount;
var videoConcurrentViewrs = video.liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers;
console.log(videoConcurrentViewrs)  // Added
```

#### Note:

- If your `videoID` is not live video, `concurrentViewers` is `undefined`. Please be careful this.

  > [`liveStreamingDetails`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos): The liveStreamingDetails object contains metadata about a live video broadcast. The object will only be present in a video resource if the video is an upcoming, live, or completed live broadcast.

#### Reference:

- [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

Comment: If I may refer to a minor issue of your answer above, I'd say that your statement (quote) *`concurrentViewers` might be `undefined`* should in fact be *`concurrentViewers` is `undefined`*. That's because the spec of [`liveStreamingDetails`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails) states that (quote) *The object will only be present in a `video` resource if the video is an upcoming, live, or completed live broadcast.* (It's not my intention to be picky; am only posting this comment for the sake of correctness.)

Comment: @stvar Thank you for your comment. At first, I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. By your comment, I could modify the answer, and also, I could study from it. Thank yo for your always support. I would like to study more and more.

Comment: I appreciate your comments: they always make apparent your open and honest approach to other people. Thank you. (For me was interesting to notice that what you're asserting about yourself I very much find it applicable to myself too.)